# Comparing two objects, what methods to call if at all

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Im wanting to compare two DNumber objects in public int compareTo(Object other)
I thought I could do something similar like the equals method above it  but I cannot call toDecimal like this

```
if(toDecimal() == other.toDecimal()){
        return 0;
    }
```

But that is not possible. What should be my next steps? Is there another way to check if they are equal? Should I use some other method.

```
public class DNumber
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own

ArrayList<Digit> binary = new ArrayList<Digit>();
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class DNumber
 */
public DNumber()
{
    Digit num = new Digit(0);
    binary.add(num);
}
public DNumber(int val){
    int num = val;
    if(num > 0){
        while (num > 0){
            Digit bin = new Digit(num%2);
            num /= 2;
            binary.add(0,bin);
        }    
    }
    else{
        Digit bin = new Digit(0);
        binary.add(0,bin);
    }
}
/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 *
 * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
 * @return    the sum of x and y
 */
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(Digit d : binary){
        s = s + d.toString();
    }
    return s;
}
public void add(DNumber b){
    int ArraySize1 = binary.size();
    int ArraySize2 = b.binary.size();
    int difference = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Digit zero = new Digit(0);
    //Checks to see the difference in arrayLists to make them equal
    if(ArraySize1 > ArraySize2){
        difference = ArraySize1 - ArraySize2;
        while(difference > i){
            b.binary.add(zero);
            ++i;
        }

    }
    else if(ArraySize1 < ArraySize2){
        difference = ArraySize2 - ArraySize1;
        while(difference > i){
            System.out.println(b.binary);
            binary.add(zero);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    else if(ArraySize1 == ArraySize2){
        difference = 0;
    }
    //System.out.println(binary + " " + "   " + b.binary);



    //To get the last value of arrays.
    Digit carry = new Digit(0);
    int j = binary.size()-1;
    while(j >= 0){
        Digit bin1 = binary.get(j);
        Digit bin2 = b.binary.get(j);
        Digit sum = bin1.add(bin2);
        System.out.println(sum);
        j--;

    }


}
public int toDecimal(){
    //Iterates through arraylist binary, creates a string, parses string to create result in decimal
    String initial = "";
    for(Digit d: binary){
    initial = initial + d.toString();  
    }
    int result = Integer.parseInt(initial, 2);
    return result;

}
//Checks to see if objects are equal.
public boolean equals(Object e){
   if( toString().equals(e.toString())){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//Returns 0 if this DNumber equals other, a negative result if this DNumber is less than other, 
// and a positive result otherwise.  You can assume that other is a DNumber
public int compareTo(Object other){


}
}
```

Comment: `public int toDecimal()` Wait, what?

Comment: Make your `DNumber` implement `Comparable<DNumber>`, then your `compareTo` method will be `public int compareTo(DNumber other)`, and you don't have to worry about comparing to all other types.

Comment: *But that is not possible* Why not?

Comment: Im not sure why the above is not possible. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Andy Turner is correct. Your DNumber should implement Comparable. That will require you to implement public int compareTo(DNumber other). However, your compareTo must be in line with equals() and hashcode(), which typically means overriding those methods as well. That is, two equal instances must return the same hashcode and compareTo() must return 0 when they are compared to each other.

Comment: The terminology in the documentation is *consistent with*, rather than "in line with"; and to be precise, `a.compareTo(b) == 0 <=> a.equals(b)`, but `a.compareTo(b) => a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` (it's not necessary for objects with equal hashcode to have `compareTo == 0`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for your `compareTo` method to take an `Object` parameter. Making it so means that you can't invoke `toDecimal()` on the parameter, because the compiler can't be sure that it will only be passed instances of `DNumber` (you could pass it a `String`, and what would it do then?).

Perhaps you're getting confused with `equals`, which needs to take an `Object` parameter in order to correctly override `Object.equals`; there is no such restriction on your `compareTo` method, because you're not overriding a method (but see below).

Change the parameter type to `DNumber`, and you'll be able to invoke `other.toDecimal()` just fine.

---

To make your class more generally useful (e.g. to allow `Collections.sort` to be able to sort `List<DNumber>`), make the class implement `Comparable`:

```
class DNumber implements Comparable<DNumber> {
  // ...

  @Override public int compareTo(DNumber other) {
    // ...
  }
}
```